# Kotlin Android: Assigning Bitmap to Imageview

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap, android-bitmap

I am building an app with Kotlin frontend/Python backend. My python script creates a .png file under getFilesDir() directory (/data/user/0/com.example.inprogress/files/mygraph.png). I then want to use kotlin to fetch the .png file and display it on imageview.

[image]

My goal is to assign Bitmap value to my imageview id graphId.

I use the code below but I get blank imageview instead of the .png file I want to display.
Note that I'm not getting any error message. Where am I doing things wrong?

```
class GraphRes : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_graphres)

        var data = intent.extras
        var graph = data!!.get("res").toString()
        // graph is where the .png file is stored
        // graph: /data/user/0/com.example.inprogress/files/mygraph.png


        var graphId = ImageView(this)
        graphId.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(graph))

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission?

If you have that and it still dont work, try the following approach:

```
graphId.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(File(graph)));
```

Or you can also use Glide library to display your image, it will do it efficiently.

Comment: Thank you. Tried your suggestions but it's still returning blank. Also I notice that my error log shows
2020-05-30 06:07:28.482 32011-32011/? E/mple.inprogres: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
Any idea what this is?

Comment: Can you view your png in your gallery? Save it in an accessible location and try to view it in your photo viewing app. Maybe your png have issues

Comment: I can open and see my .png file in gallery and it is saved under an accessible location.

Comment: OK, you can do a few things. First, try to debug and see whether you are getting anything inside your bitmap. Second, check whether the path is correct. 3rd, try with Glide library. Also, try by giving `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission

Comment: When I debug, I get the following assigned to graphId and I can open my .png file fine.
mDrawable = {BitmapDrawable@10014} ""...View Bitmap